# Polygon in Kinetic.js 4.0.2 broken?

Tags: javascript, polygon, kineticjs

I upgraded my scripts to use kinetic.js 4.0.2 because of another bugfix. Now all elements I created as Polygon ar not showing up anymore. If I console.log() on the objects they seem to exist but they are not drawn.

Even the minimum Polygon:

```
var test = new Kinetic.Polygon({
        points: [10,10,20,50, 100,100,10,10]
    });
```

does not show up. Any other things lines, text, images work still fine.

Did anyone also notices this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Kinetic is starting to enforce x, y pair mappings for points and no longer accepting one long array of co-ordinates. You can see it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/rALbw/8/

Comment: This also happened to me for circle radius, you can't use an array any more, only a number.

Comment: Awesome! Works fine...did I miss some release note what describes that? Because thats kind of a breaking change I think.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I just had a quick look at them but can't see anything about it. I only noticed yours because similar happened to me. Kinetic is great but I find the documentation and tutorials aren't always up-to-date, which is where problems usually come from.